# Send email with attachment

Tags: 7, hooks, emails

I want to send an attachment with `drupal_mail()` using `hook_mail_alter()`. Do you have any ideas about which parameter should I use?

Does the variable `$param` help, in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mail implementation in Drupal does not support attachments.

You will need one of the contrib mail modules which support attachments, for example http://drupal.org/project/mailmime. I wasn't able to find any useful docs and it seems that the [maintainer is aware of it](http://drupal.org/node/1122254) and hopefully working on something.